# How to create multiple instances of MagicMock

Tags: python, python-unittest

Let's assume I have a class `MyEntity` that has an attribute `id` and method `do_something()` and a class `MyEntityProcessor` that has a method `process_enities_list()`, the method requires a list of entities and does some processing calling `do_something()` for each entity.

I want to test `process_entities_list()` with unittest and MagicMock. I think ideally code should look somehow like this

```
class TestProcessor(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("MyEntity", autospec=True)
    def test_processing(self, MockEntity):
        entities = []
        for i in range(5):
            entities.append(MockEntity(id = i))

        result = process_entities_list(entities)

        for entity in entities:
            entity.do_something.assert_called_once()
```

But `MockEntity()` always returns the same copy of MagickMock object, so the test does not work as intended.

I can replace `MockTree` with just 'Mock' but then I lose the advantage of checking that the tested method uses correct interface to communicate with an entity.

Is there some way to fix this issue?

Is there something wrong with my test design? Is there a better architecture to make this case easier to test?

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't instantiate `Mock` or `MagicMock` with `spec=MockEntity` set, rather than patching the `MockEntity` class itself?

Comment: This seems to work, thank you